# How to align the navigation menu in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, css, alignment, wordpress-theming

I have a problem.. I can't make the navigation into horizontal.. Please teach me how to align the navigation menu into horizontal and place it in center in WordPress?

I'm newbie in WordPress.. Please help me

Thanks!

Here's the css for navigation:

```
#toppart #mainnav {
margin: 40px 0 0;
max-width: 100%;
float:none;
text-align:center;
}

#toppart #mainnav ul li {
float: none;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display:inline;
background: #16212b;
padding: 9px 14px;
}

#toppart #mainnav ul li a {
margin:0;
padding:9px 14px;
display: inline;
}

#toppart #mainnav ul ul {
display: inline;
float: none;
position: relative;
margin-left:20px;
top:0;
left: 0;
z-index:none;
text-align:center;
}

#toppart #mainnav ul ul ul {
display: inline;
float: none;
position: relative;
margin-left:40px;
top:0;
left: 0;
z-index:none;
text-align:center;
}

#toppart #mainnav ul ul li {
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
text-align:center;
}

#toppart #mainnav ul ul ul li {
border-bottom:none;
text-align:center;
}

#toppart #mainnav ul ul li a {
background:none;
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
list-style:square;
text-align:center;
}

#toppart #mainnav ul li a:hover {
background:none;
text-align:center;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use somethink like

```
#toppart #mainnav ul ul li {
float: left;
position: relative;
}
```

In the Wordpress menus you are going to have all the items inside `li` tags so you can use the properties `float: left;` and `position: relative;` to get them aligned horizontally

It is not necessary to change the display property

Comment: OK it is better if you have and example where the people can see a real part of code, I mean no just the css, do you have the website?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you have given float left to particular.

```
#toppart #mainnav ul li { 
float: left;
list-style: none;
position:relative;
display:inline;
background: #16212b;
padding: 9px 14px;
}
```

i think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```css
  #toppart #mainnav ul ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
     margin-left:20px;
display:inline;
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: #toppart #mainnav ul ul li {

Change this part with the code I have provided and see what happens.